How do I POST a file and name:value pairs to a Website
This is my first post.....
I am trying to upload data to a web site using C# and HttpClient.
The site responds when I use curl:
curl -X POST https://www.eQSL.cc/qslcard/ImportADIF.cfm -F "Filename=@"D:\Documents\SourceCode\Radio\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows\logfile.adi"

And I get back:
<!-- Reply form eQSL.cc ADIF Real-time Interface -->
etc.....

My C# code returns a status code "OK", but the response is an empty string.
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

//https://www.eqsl.cc/QSLcard/ImportADIF.txt  HOW TO USE THE "ImportADIF.cfm" PROGRAM for eQSL.cc
//https://www.eqsl.cc/QSLCard/ADIFContentSpecs.cfm

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string response = UploadLog(client).Result;
        }

        /*
         curl -v POST https://www.eQSL.cc/qslcard/ImportADIF.cfm -F "Filename=@"D:\Documents\SourceCode\Radio\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows\logfile.adi"
        returns a Web response
        */
        private static async Task<string>  UploadLog(HttpClient client)
        {
            string url = @"https://www.eQSL.cc/qslcard/ImportADIF.cfm";
            string filePath = @"D:\Documents\SourceCode\Radio\bin\Debug\net8.0-windows\logfile.adi";

            byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

            MultipartFormDataContent formContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            StreamContent fileContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);

            fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
            {
                Name = "Filename",
                FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath)
            };

            formContent.Add(fileContent);
            formContent.Add(new StringContent("myUserID"), "EQSL_USER");
            formContent.Add(new StringContent("myPass"), "EQSL_PSWD");

            var response = await client.PostAsync(url, formContent);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

    }
}


"My C# code returns a status code "OK", but the response is an empty string." what are you expecting to be returned? Is there a GET request you can send to verify that your file has been uploaded?

I should be getting:  and then some HTML. I can go to the site and verify that my file has not been uploaded.
